# Moving files to corresponding folder based on name

Tags: python, move

I am trying to move files to a corresponding folder based on their filename in Python. There are 3 identifiers, the genre i.e. "DRAMA", the director i.e. "von Trier", and the movie name i.e. "Melancholia". So the file "DRAMA von Trier Melancholia" would need to be moved to say, C:/shared/com/movies/DRAMA/Melancholia/von Trier. There are  many files located that need to be moved, so I would rather not hard code the locations/do it 1 by 1. Here is what I have so far which lists all the files I want moved, but does not actually move them.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/shared/com/movies/'):
    print dirpath
    print dirs
    print files
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('*.mov'):
            shutil.move('') #not sure how to code this to have it move based on paramaters rather than hard coding it
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the information about the filename by using the modul os.path and using split or splittext. After that you can split the filename with the modul re. With the parts and mkdir you can create the necessary dirs. Could you give an example for a filename?

Comment: DRAMA von trier Melancholia.mov   which I would then want to move to the folder C:/shared/com/movies/DRAMA/Melancholia/von Trier

Comment: Could be difficult to extract the director and the name of the film with regular expressions, because there is no way, to decide, whether the director is just "von" or (right) "von Trier".